# Why "Wo" and not "Was"?

Tags: translation, english-to-german, question

In the following sentence why using `Was` instead of `Wo` is not possible?

> Wo arbeitet Hans?

according to my book the only possible W-question is `Wo`

Comment: Wo arbeitet Hans? Im Krankenhaus. Als was arbeitet Hans? Als Pförtner.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Arbeiten* is (in standard German) an intransitive verb, i.e. it cannot have an accusative object; which is what you would be asking for with *was*. When asking for an occupation, the question is:

> Als was arbeitet Hans? Hans arbeitet als Maurer.

With *wo*, you ask for the place. This can give you a hint about the occupation, but it is usually less specific, and it may also prompt a completely different answer:

> Wo arbeitet Hans? Hans arbeitet auf dem Bau. Hans arbeitet in Frankfurt.

In colloquial language, *Was arbeitet Hans?* is sometimes heard, but it wouldn't be considered correct.

It is not true that *wo* is the only possible question word. You can of course ask:

> Warum arbeitet Hans? Wie arbeitet Hans? Wann arbeitet Hans?

Comment: We can also hear "An/Mit/Für [...] was arbeitet Hans" - this indicates that we need a preposition here like in "Für wen/Mit wem/Bei wem arbeitet Hans".

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, I'm a new German learner and its very confusing right now. Many thanks...

Comment: In colloquial German the question "Was arbeitet Hans" does exist... maybe not with Hans, because he is on Hartz4 as far as I know but anyway... It can either ask for the profession  "Was arbeitet der?" "Der is' Zahnarzt". I think this use might be a rephrased "Was machst du?"... the second meaning is "Why?"... "Was arbeitest du? Geh mal lieber auf's Amt." This is asking why the person is working. I think this comes from Kiezdeutsch and there similar phrasings with "was" the most prominent one being "Was guckst du?" or "Was lachst du?"